# ReactJS and PHP Fetch Syntax error related to '<'

Tags: php, reactjs

I have an issue with this React and PHP Fetch. It is complaining about a Syntax error '<' on line 21 where I have my return with `<li> </li>` tags. I had a few people look at it and they can't figure out why the error is occurring. Everything looks good but it is complaining. I am hoping other people on the Internet can potentially notice why the error is occurring as this is likely a very very small issue causing the error.

Thank you for the help!

Below is the code for the index.html. It works in conjunction with a backend.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> ReactJS AJAX with Fetch </title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"  crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"  crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"> </div>
    
    <script>
        class DemoList extends React.Component {
            constructor (props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { dataFetch:[] }
            }
            
            renderData({id, name, grade})
            {
                return <li key={id}>{name}....{grade}</li> //Line 21 HERE
            }   
            
            componentDidMount() {
                fetch("backend.php")
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => 
                            {
                                this.setState({dataFetch:data});
                            });
            }
            
            render() {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h1> Data </h1>
                        <ul>
                            {this.state.dataFetch.map(this.renderData.bind(this))} 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
        <DemoList/>,
        document.querySelector("#container")
        );
    </script>

</body>
```

Backend.php file

```
 <?php 
    echo json_encode([
        ["id" => "1", "name"=>"Jane","grade"=>"D-"],
        ["id" => "2", "name"=>"Toby","grade"=>"A+"],
        ["id" => "3", "name"=>"John","grade"=>"C+"],
        ["id" => "4", "name"=>"Doe","grade"=>"A-"],     
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to put that in quotes? otherwise js is trying to interpret it.

Comment: Nope, I just had someone else get back to me and it turns out all I am missing is type="text/babel" in the opening script tag. So without that, it may interpret it as something else. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: you are writing JSX which browsers cannot 'understand'. You need to transform your JSX to JS.